# Ajax jsonp call triggers fail although response seems ok

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Im calling a php script with a jsonp ajax call. My issue is that I cant get the callback to trigger "success" - my data is processed and saved by my php script and reponse seems ok also.

I've been trying with the following:

```
var url = "my.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

var request = $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: url,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       data: { name: signupName, email: signupEmail, date: signupDate},
       success: function(data)
       {
            if(data.returned_val == "succes") {
                //all good
            }
       },
       error:function() {
            console.log("fail");
        }   
     });
  return false;
}
```

From my php script im printing out a json response that looks like: `{"returned_val":"succes"}`

Comment: jsonp needs a callback function - you may want to change that to json

Answer (score 0):

JSONP require that the server returns the response wrapped in a callback function. Basically, your PHP script should respond the following

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo $_GET['callback'].'({"returned_val":"succes"})';
```

That way, JS will accept the response as valid and trigger the success callback.

Comment: something like this?
echo $_GET['callback'].json_encode(array('returned_val' => 'succes')); - tried that with no luck :( ... Btw that return the following response: jQuery1102009731390838320186_1424959177965{"returned_val":"succes"}

Comment: Sorry. Wrong quotes! it should have been: echo $_GET['callback'].'({"returned_val":"succes"})';

Comment: Tried the updated one and it now gives me: ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Comment: oh, seems I just had to define: jsonpCallback: 'callback', - and now it works! Cheers!

Comment: Indeed, I was just typing that. Sorry I missed it